# I have a rooted device, how can i build my application as system app?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have a rooted device, how can i build my application as system app? 
My main objective is to have permissions as of a system app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create System Apps in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333951/how-to-create-system-apps-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Download an app App2Rom from playstore and then move your app to system files. Furthermore, To give superuser functionality to your app add this code.

```
 Process p;
    try {

        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```