# how to convert app to system app ?

Tags: android, shell

How do install a *.apk from adb command line?

First I tried to cp the *.apk from /sdcard/backups/apps to /system/app (after rw mounting the file system of course)

I did successfully move it to /system/app but the *apk was not "installed"

I used this code :-

**
adb shell

su

mount -o rw,remount /system

adb shell

su

cd /sdcard

mv com.ogp.gpstoggler-1.apk /system/priv-app

finally after I write

chown 644 /system/priv-app/com.ogp.gpstoggler-1.apk

and press enter the result is

---

Unable to open /system/priv-app/com.ogp.gpstoggler-1.apk: No such file or direc
tory***

how to fix this ? thank you ?

Comment: You need root access to do this.

Comment: why can't use adb install?

Comment: Also note - adding an APK to the system partition does not make it a system app (that is an app with system-level privileges). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333951/how-to-create-system-apps-in-android/17640635

Comment: Im upvoting you because people suck - there is no reason you should of been downvoted. You have a decent question of how to install an app in the priv-app folder - which I do weekly.

Comment: My phone was rooted and has superuser access

Answer (score 3):

1. Instead of using "mv" use "cp" to copy it to system/priv-app folder.
2. Ensure it is in the priv-app folder using "ls"
3. use chmod 777 to give it privileges
4. Ensure it has the correct privileges using "ls -l"
5. use "adb reboot" to have the system install the application.

   ***Edit***

One thing I forgot to note - if you go into the system/priv-app folder and you see that all the other APK's are in their own folders, you might also have to create a folder for your apk.

1. mkdir system/priv-app/app_name
2. cp app_name.apk system/priv-app/app_name
3. cd system/priv-app/app_name
4. chmod 777 system/priv-app/app_name/app_name.apk
5. adb reboot

Comment: Can app name always be a name of a folder? And how can I convert the app back to be a user app?

Comment: is it still working on android 11 ?